# excel pivot table: multiple conditions for same variable

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in excel with 3 variables in the ROWS: Channel, DEMO2, Market.

I would like to:

-keep "NetherlandsA20-49" Demo for "DNI Portfolio" channel AND
-keep "NetherlandsM20-49" Demo for "Discovery Channel" in the same pivot table.

Is there a workaround? vba? any other tricks?

here is what the pivot table looks like:

[image]

Here is what I want the pivot table to look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how your preferred output would look like? If you want to aggregate the values for NetherlandsM20-49 etc, just drop the "Channel" column from the Pivot Table

Comment: @Axel - the grey rows highlighted would not appear in this pivot table basically. Trouble is, for Netherlands each channel uses a different demo hence I have to select all those demos.

Comment: if its only about hiding certain combinations, a workaround could be to manipulate the raw data. If you have a table of allowed combinations of channels, demos and countries, you could create a macro which flags all other combinations and then filters them in your pivot table. If I have more time later, I will write a more detailed answer.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. No need for a detailed answer, i think i should be able to achieve this.